# Running VNC viewer from windows 8.1 to Debian Jessie, doesn't work

Tags: debian, windows, vnc

I'm trying to implement a vncviewer on my windows 8.1 to remote my server running Debian Jessie with DE Gnome 3.14.1 but it doesn't work.

I've verified my xstartup file and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrexec
gnome-session &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

With that I only obtain the gray screen, I've been modified the xstartup file lots and lots of time but I don't get this work, in every change the message I obtain apart the gray screen is the message:

`Oh no! Something has gone wrong.`

Please I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776746

> Now I can sum up the conclution of this bug:
>
> 1) It won't be fixed in
>   Jessie although it also influences wheezy;
>
> 2) For developers: Tigervnc
>   should be included in Debian 9 and replace tightvnc,
>       if not, this issue won't be fixed in Debian 9; probably should consider a Jessie
>       backport when Tigervnc is available;
>
> 3) For system administrators and normal users: IF you want to use remote desktop
>       server in Jessie, DO NOT use default desktop (GNOME). If you really like GNOME
>       or other GNOME3's fork (Unity, Cinnamon, etc), then DO NOT use Debian or
>       other Debian based distributions (Ubuntu, Mint, etc). Alternatively, try Red hat
>       based or SUSE based distributions (CentOS, Fedora, OpenSUSE, SLE, etc). They
>       already have tigervnc and can work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @jgilligan I've tried remote my server using E17 instead gnome desktop environment and following the same process it's works...but now I have another problem that is that some keys doesn't respond on vnc viewer. Can you help with this issue, please? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that right now there is a bug in the distro (kali/debian with GNOME) causing both VNC and RDP to cause that error message after login.

The only way I found that fixes this is to uninstall the Gnome-desktop and use another window manager (I use LXDE):

```
# apt-get remove gnome-core
# apt-get install lxde-core lxde kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base
# update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
    # Choose /usr/bin/startlxde
```

After this you need to reboot and the RDP should work perfectly.

Comment: Is it really necessary to remove gnome? Will just adding LXDE or XFCE not work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to allow Windows 8.1 to connect is described [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/24/debian-8-remote-connect-to-gnome3-desktop-with-vnc-xrdp/#sec-1). It uses tigervnc from the ubuntu repo.

Comment: FWIW this fix is not just to allow Win8 to connect over RDP. The workaround is required for RDP *and* VNC to work on a Debian jessie server/host (regardless of the client OS)